# AES_DECRYPT SELECT WHERE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have an encrypted MySQL DB. When I do a select where, it is not returning any value.

`SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(`email`, 'salt') as CHAR(100)) AS email FROM`table`WHERE email = 'test@email.com'` returns no result.

`SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(`email`, 'salt') as CHAR(100)) AS email FROM`table`` returns results, with the test@email.com in the result set.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.

`SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(`email`, 'salt') as CHAR(100)) AS email FROM`table`WHERE cast(aes_decrypt(`email`, 'salt) as CHAR(100)) = 'test@email.com'`